# Cómo colocar numeración página con la librería iTextSharp ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itextsharp

Estoy realizando exportación a PDF con la librería `iTextSharp`, me genera correctamente el documento pero lo que desearía es colocar una numeración de página en el PDF y para ello estoy realizando con este codigo:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Simulador_Credito.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

StringWriter swr = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htmlwr = new HtmlTextWriter(swr);
StringReader srr = new StringReader(swr.ToString());
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

htmlparser.Parse(srr);
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

Pero, no me muestra la numeración de página y tampoco me envía errores.

Aquí dejo todo el código:

```
protected void btnPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A3, 10f, 10f, 10f, 10f);

            iTextSharp.text.Document oDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER);
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter pdfww = default(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter);      
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();

            GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#c6efce");
            Font line = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", size: 12);
            Font lin1e = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", size: 8);
            Font LineBreak = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", size: 14);
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            string FechaActual = today.ToString("dd-MM-yyy");
            var FechaActualImpresion = new Paragraph("FECHA DE IMPRESION: " + FechaActual);
            FechaActualImpresion.Alignment = 2;

            TextAlign LineBreaks = TextAlign.Left;
            HorizontalAlign horiz = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("\n\n", lin1e));
            byte[] file;
            file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/img/LOGOQAPAQ.png"));
            iTextSharp.text.Image PNG = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(file);
            PNG.ScaleAbsolute(159f, 60f);
            PNG.Alignment = 1;
            pdfDoc.Add(PNG);
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("\n\n", lin1e));
            var boldFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);

            Font verdanaBold = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 20f, Font.UNDERLINE);
            var nombresimulador = new Paragraph("SIMULADOR DE CRÉDITOS", verdanaBold);
            nombresimulador.Alignment = 1;
            nombresimulador.Font.Size = 18;
            pdfDoc.Add(nombresimulador);
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("\n\n", line));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("\n\n", line));
            HorizontalAlign Horizontal = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("CRONOGRAMA PRELIMINAR DE PAGOS"));
            pdfDoc.Add(FechaActualImpresion);
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("\n\n", line));

            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("\n\n", line));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("\n\n", line));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("La cotización obtenida no representa la aprobación del crédito, la cual está sujeta a la evaluación crediticia que debe realizar la Financiera. Este simulador es referencial, en base a la información ingresada."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta simulación no incluye ITF (Impuesto a las Transacciones Financieras), consulte el tarifario del producto, antes de realizar la simulación."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("El seguro de desgravamen es financiado y se calcula sobre el monto principal del crédito. El costo del seguro es el cobrado por la Aseguradora; de acuerdo a las condiciones establecidas por ésta."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Infórmate sobre nuestras tasas de interés, comisiones, gastos y penalidades en el tarifario ubicado en la red de Agencias o en www.qapaq.pe."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta información se proporciona de acuerdo al Reglamento de Transparencia de Información y Disposiciones Aplicables a la Contratación con Usuarios del Sistema Financiero, aprobado mediante Resolución SBS N° 8181-2012."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("La cotización obtenida no representa la aprobación del crédito, la cual está sujeta a la evaluación crediticia que debe realizar la Financiera. Este simulador es referencial, en base a la información ingresada."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta simulación no incluye ITF (Impuesto a las Transacciones Financieras), consulte el tarifario del producto, antes de realizar la simulación."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("El seguro de desgravamen es financiado y se calcula sobre el monto principal del crédito. El costo del seguro es el cobrado por la Aseguradora; de acuerdo a las condiciones establecidas por ésta."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Infórmate sobre nuestras tasas de interés, comisiones, gastos y penalidades en el tarifario ubicado en la red de Agencias o en www.qapaq.pe."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta información se proporciona de acuerdo al Reglamento de Transparencia de Información y Disposiciones Aplicables a la Contratación con Usuarios del Sistema Financiero, aprobado mediante Resolución SBS N° 8181-2012."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("La cotización obtenida no representa la aprobación del crédito, la cual está sujeta a la evaluación crediticia que debe realizar la Financiera. Este simulador es referencial, en base a la información ingresada."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta simulación no incluye ITF (Impuesto a las Transacciones Financieras), consulte el tarifario del producto, antes de realizar la simulación."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("El seguro de desgravamen es financiado y se calcula sobre el monto principal del crédito. El costo del seguro es el cobrado por la Aseguradora; de acuerdo a las condiciones establecidas por ésta."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Infórmate sobre nuestras tasas de interés, comisiones, gastos y penalidades en el tarifario ubicado en la red de Agencias o en www.qapaq.pe."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta información se proporciona de acuerdo al Reglamento de Transparencia de Información y Disposiciones Aplicables a la Contratación con Usuarios del Sistema Financiero, aprobado mediante Resolución SBS N° 8181-2012."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("La cotización obtenida no representa la aprobación del crédito, la cual está sujeta a la evaluación crediticia que debe realizar la Financiera. Este simulador es referencial, en base a la información ingresada."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta simulación no incluye ITF (Impuesto a las Transacciones Financieras), consulte el tarifario del producto, antes de realizar la simulación."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("El seguro de desgravamen es financiado y se calcula sobre el monto principal del crédito. El costo del seguro es el cobrado por la Aseguradora; de acuerdo a las condiciones establecidas por ésta."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Infórmate sobre nuestras tasas de interés, comisiones, gastos y penalidades en el tarifario ubicado en la red de Agencias o en www.qapaq.pe."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta información se proporciona de acuerdo al Reglamento de Transparencia de Información y Disposiciones Aplicables a la Contratación con Usuarios del Sistema Financiero, aprobado mediante Resolución SBS N° 8181-2012."));

            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("La cotización obtenida no representa la aprobación del crédito, la cual está sujeta a la evaluación crediticia que debe realizar la Financiera. Este simulador es referencial, en base a la información ingresada."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta simulación no incluye ITF (Impuesto a las Transacciones Financieras), consulte el tarifario del producto, antes de realizar la simulación."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("El seguro de desgravamen es financiado y se calcula sobre el monto principal del crédito. El costo del seguro es el cobrado por la Aseguradora; de acuerdo a las condiciones establecidas por ésta."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Infórmate sobre nuestras tasas de interés, comisiones, gastos y penalidades en el tarifario ubicado en la red de Agencias o en www.qapaq.pe."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta información se proporciona de acuerdo al Reglamento de Transparencia de Información y Disposiciones Aplicables a la Contratación con Usuarios del Sistema Financiero, aprobado mediante Resolución SBS N° 8181-2012."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("La cotización obtenida no representa la aprobación del crédito, la cual está sujeta a la evaluación crediticia que debe realizar la Financiera. Este simulador es referencial, en base a la información ingresada."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta simulación no incluye ITF (Impuesto a las Transacciones Financieras), consulte el tarifario del producto, antes de realizar la simulación."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("El seguro de desgravamen es financiado y se calcula sobre el monto principal del crédito. El costo del seguro es el cobrado por la Aseguradora; de acuerdo a las condiciones establecidas por ésta."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Infórmate sobre nuestras tasas de interés, comisiones, gastos y penalidades en el tarifario ubicado en la red de Agencias o en www.qapaq.pe."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta información se proporciona de acuerdo al Reglamento de Transparencia de Información y Disposiciones Aplicables a la Contratación con Usuarios del Sistema Financiero, aprobado mediante Resolución SBS N° 8181-2012."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("La cotización obtenida no representa la aprobación del crédito, la cual está sujeta a la evaluación crediticia que debe realizar la Financiera. Este simulador es referencial, en base a la información ingresada."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta simulación no incluye ITF (Impuesto a las Transacciones Financieras), consulte el tarifario del producto, antes de realizar la simulación."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("El seguro de desgravamen es financiado y se calcula sobre el monto principal del crédito. El costo del seguro es el cobrado por la Aseguradora; de acuerdo a las condiciones establecidas por ésta."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Infórmate sobre nuestras tasas de interés, comisiones, gastos y penalidades en el tarifario ubicado en la red de Agencias o en www.qapaq.pe."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta información se proporciona de acuerdo al Reglamento de Transparencia de Información y Disposiciones Aplicables a la Contratación con Usuarios del Sistema Financiero, aprobado mediante Resolución SBS N° 8181-2012."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("La cotización obtenida no representa la aprobación del crédito, la cual está sujeta a la evaluación crediticia que debe realizar la Financiera. Este simulador es referencial, en base a la información ingresada."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta simulación no incluye ITF (Impuesto a las Transacciones Financieras), consulte el tarifario del producto, antes de realizar la simulación."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("El seguro de desgravamen es financiado y se calcula sobre el monto principal del crédito. El costo del seguro es el cobrado por la Aseguradora; de acuerdo a las condiciones establecidas por ésta."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Infórmate sobre nuestras tasas de interés, comisiones, gastos y penalidades en el tarifario ubicado en la red de Agencias o en www.qapaq.pe."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta información se proporciona de acuerdo al Reglamento de Transparencia de Información y Disposiciones Aplicables a la Contratación con Usuarios del Sistema Financiero, aprobado mediante Resolución SBS N° 8181-2012."));

            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("La cotización obtenida no representa la aprobación del crédito, la cual está sujeta a la evaluación crediticia que debe realizar la Financiera. Este simulador es referencial, en base a la información ingresada."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta simulación no incluye ITF (Impuesto a las Transacciones Financieras), consulte el tarifario del producto, antes de realizar la simulación."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("El seguro de desgravamen es financiado y se calcula sobre el monto principal del crédito. El costo del seguro es el cobrado por la Aseguradora; de acuerdo a las condiciones establecidas por ésta."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Infórmate sobre nuestras tasas de interés, comisiones, gastos y penalidades en el tarifario ubicado en la red de Agencias o en www.qapaq.pe."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta información se proporciona de acuerdo al Reglamento de Transparencia de Información y Disposiciones Aplicables a la Contratación con Usuarios del Sistema Financiero, aprobado mediante Resolución SBS N° 8181-2012."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("La cotización obtenida no representa la aprobación del crédito, la cual está sujeta a la evaluación crediticia que debe realizar la Financiera. Este simulador es referencial, en base a la información ingresada."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta simulación no incluye ITF (Impuesto a las Transacciones Financieras), consulte el tarifario del producto, antes de realizar la simulación."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("El seguro de desgravamen es financiado y se calcula sobre el monto principal del crédito. El costo del seguro es el cobrado por la Aseguradora; de acuerdo a las condiciones establecidas por ésta."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Infórmate sobre nuestras tasas de interés, comisiones, gastos y penalidades en el tarifario ubicado en la red de Agencias o en www.qapaq.pe."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta información se proporciona de acuerdo al Reglamento de Transparencia de Información y Disposiciones Aplicables a la Contratación con Usuarios del Sistema Financiero, aprobado mediante Resolución SBS N° 8181-2012."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("La cotización obtenida no representa la aprobación del crédito, la cual está sujeta a la evaluación crediticia que debe realizar la Financiera. Este simulador es referencial, en base a la información ingresada."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta simulación no incluye ITF (Impuesto a las Transacciones Financieras), consulte el tarifario del producto, antes de realizar la simulación."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("El seguro de desgravamen es financiado y se calcula sobre el monto principal del crédito. El costo del seguro es el cobrado por la Aseguradora; de acuerdo a las condiciones establecidas por ésta."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Infórmate sobre nuestras tasas de interés, comisiones, gastos y penalidades en el tarifario ubicado en la red de Agencias o en www.qapaq.pe."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta información se proporciona de acuerdo al Reglamento de Transparencia de Información y Disposiciones Aplicables a la Contratación con Usuarios del Sistema Financiero, aprobado mediante Resolución SBS N° 8181-2012."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("La cotización obtenida no representa la aprobación del crédito, la cual está sujeta a la evaluación crediticia que debe realizar la Financiera. Este simulador es referencial, en base a la información ingresada."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta simulación no incluye ITF (Impuesto a las Transacciones Financieras), consulte el tarifario del producto, antes de realizar la simulación."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("El seguro de desgravamen es financiado y se calcula sobre el monto principal del crédito. El costo del seguro es el cobrado por la Aseguradora; de acuerdo a las condiciones establecidas por ésta."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Infórmate sobre nuestras tasas de interés, comisiones, gastos y penalidades en el tarifario ubicado en la red de Agencias o en www.qapaq.pe."));
            pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Esta información se proporciona de acuerdo al Reglamento de Transparencia de Información y Disposiciones Aplicables a la Contratación con Usuarios del Sistema Financiero, aprobado mediante Resolución SBS N° 8181-2012."));     
            pdfDoc.Close();

            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Simulador_Credito.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

            StringWriter swr = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmlwr = new HtmlTextWriter(swr);
            StringReader srr = new StringReader(swr.ToString());
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

            htmlparser.Parse(srr);
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que primero tienen que realizar es crear una clase , la que la llamaremos :
**PageEventHelper**

```
 public class PageEventHelper : PdfPageEventHelper
    {
        PdfContentByte cb;
        PdfTemplate template;


        public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            cb = writer.DirectContent;
            template = cb.CreateTemplate(50, 50);
        }

        public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document doc)
        {

            BaseColor grey = new BaseColor(128, 128, 128);
            iTextSharp.text.Font font = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, grey);
            //tbl footer
            PdfPTable footerTbl = new PdfPTable(1);
            footerTbl.TotalWidth = doc.PageSize.Width;



            //numero de la page

            Chunk myFooter = new Chunk("Página " + (doc.PageNumber), FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_OBLIQUE, 8, grey));
            PdfPCell footer = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(myFooter));
            footer.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
            footer.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            footerTbl.AddCell(footer);


            footerTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, (doc.BottomMargin + 80), writer.DirectContent);
        }




        public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnCloseDocument(writer, document);

        }
    }
```

esa clase nos mostrara si tiene 2 o mas paginas el pdf y nos mostrara.

ahora tan solo debemos que llamar la clase al proyecto y listo para eso ingresamos este codigo:

```
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
wri.PageEvent = new PageEventHelper();
```